# Google Distance Matrix vs Google Maps vs Direction Service Difference

Tags: c#, google-maps, google-distancematrix-api

I am working on the application where I need to calculate the distance between 2 points on road. I am trying to make use of the Google API's to find the same.

However, I am seeing the difference in between Distance calculate by Distance Matrix/Direction Service vs Google Map.

e.g.
Distance Matrix Call -

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&mode=driving&origins=32.9068408094901%2C-117.16891048788365&destinations=32.88825094509964%2C-117.21174850405791
```

Returns Data as
[image]
Direction Service API Call -

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=32.9068408094901%2C-117.16891048788365&destination=32.88825094509964%2C-117.21174850405791
```

Returns data as
[image]

However, Google Map returns completely different results
[image]

I want to understand -

1. Difference between Distance Matrix API and Direction service? They return same distance
2. Why Google Maps return completely different distance?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not the correct channel to ask this. If you want a precise answer, you can contact the Google Maps Platform support team by filing a support case: https://developers.google.com/maps/support/#creating-a-support-case

Comment: Just to provide some context, [Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/overview) will only provide the travel distance and time for a matrix of origins and destinations while [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions) provide the step by step directions, number of turns, from one point to another.